# How to run a Mongoose query for each result to aggregate the data?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to know if a user liked a book and display a heart depending on the state (liked/ not liked) in the results in my view.

The problem is that the value from the second query is not available outside of that function.

I tried using a async function inside but that gives back no result. I also tried adding the books to an array and return that, this gives an empty array.

```
var bookQuery = Book.find({ title: req.body.title}, {}, { skip: 0, limit: 200 })
.sort({ name: 1 });

bookQuery.lean().exec(function (err, books) {
  books = books.map(function (book) {
    Like.findOne({ object: book._id, likedby: req.session.passport.user }).exec(function (err, like) {
      book.liked = (like != null) ? 1 : 0;
      // Here it's available
    });

    return book;
  });

  cb(books);
}, cb);
```

I want to add a field for each book with the value from the Like query.
Right now it only displays the books.

Answer (score 1):

So as you know a lot of things are async in Node JS, you are not able to get the result from outside of the callback function. For callbacks, you can just use [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module in order to avoid [callback hells](http://callbackhell.com/). [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module is very popular among Node JS developers so if you use callbacks, I strongly recommend to use [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async). It has dozens of methods which facilitate and flourish your code.

However, with ES6 comes a lot of new and helpful functions. One of these functions is [Promise](https://javascript.info/promise-basics). It is developed based on callbacks and it makes easy to code async functions. There is also one easy way to overcome asynchronous functions is [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await). Actually, there are [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I'm aware of async in Node.js and have tried the async/ await on Like.findOne but I can't get it to work and the map function can't be asynchronous.

Getting the books out and display them works fine, I just cannot get the like part added.

Comment: I can't seem to find any examples online about running nested queries in Mongoose like what I'm trying to do above. Could you give an example?